# Kotlin coroutine immediately give an exception if last operation finished with exception

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

When I was try to login on my service via retrofit. When my service is off, 10 seconds after clicking the button I got an `SocketTimeoutException` exception. 
So far everything is normal but again, I clicked the button again after the error gave the same error immediately. What's wrong?

```
interface LoginService {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/login")
    fun login(@Field("id") id: String, @Field("pw") pw: String): Deferred<Response<User>>

}

class LoginViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private var job: Job = Job()
    private val scope: CoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + job)
    private val service by lazy { RetrofitApiFactory().create(LoginService::class.java) }
    private val excHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, throwable ->
        Timber.e(throwable);
    }

    fun doLogin(id: String, pw: String) {
        scope.launch(excHandler) {
            val response = service.login(id, pw).await()
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                response.body()
                        ?.let { user -> doOnSuccess(user) }
                        ?: doOnError(InvalidUserException())
            } else doOnError(Exception())
        }
    }

    private fun CoroutineScope.doOnError(e: Throwable) {
        excHandler.handleException(coroutineContext, e)
    }

    private fun doOnSuccess(user: User) {
        ...
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        job.cancel()
    }

}
```

Comment: I see a big problem in this design, it has several channels to communicate an error. First there's the `Response` which may be successful or not, then there's the `Deferred`, which may be completed or cancelled. In a good design there would be no `Deferred` but a `suspend fun` instead, and it would signal all errors through exceptions. If you get a response, it means it's successful.

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/342#issuecomment-383841713) for a thorough explanation of the philosophy behind `suspend fun` vs. `Deferred`.

Comment: I can't use without `Deferred`. Its give an error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for retrofit2.Response`

Comment: Yes, from what I know, Retrofit only supports the `Deferred`, but I think it should support `suspend fun` as well. Did you declare your function as `suspend fun`?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/pull/2886), the `suspend fun` support is coming out as soon as Kotlin 1.3 comes out.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change your `CoroutineScope` to not re-use the same `Job`. It's already considered as **failed**, so it will not even begin executing.

See [related issue on github](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/686).

Comment: This advice is fatally wrong, it undoes the reason why the master job exists in the first place. The best advice is _don't let the exception escape unhandled_. If that's not an option, then take the advice from the GitHub issue and use a `SupervisorJob` instead of `Job`.